# Why does my GNOME settings mention "Moto C Plus"?

Tags: gnome, gdm

As you can see in this picture:

[image: "Moto C Plus Off" in menu]

my (no idea what its name is) system menu shows both "G4 Off" and "Moto C Plus Off". The "G4 Off" is there since forever and it always had the same submenu points as the "Moto C Plus Off" option but "Moto C Plus Off" is new since today I think. I don't own a Motorola, the laptop is not a Motorola. Where does this come from and how can I get rid of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Android devices nowadays allows you to share internet via Bluetooth also. These are the Bluetooth devices that have capability to share internet via Bluetooth. These devices were paired with your Ubuntu (most probably unknowingly, since you don't know from where they came). To remove them, go to Bluetooth Settings. The device must be showing disconnected like this:

[image]

Use Left Mouse Click and remove the device.

[image]

The device must now have gone from drop-down menu too. Also, try to keep your Bluetooth off when not in use to save power and "anonymous" device connections.

Comment: Gnah, thank you. The list does **not** contain the Phillips headphones  I would instantly have associated in this way. Checking who in this house has a Moto C Plus now :D

Comment: @Giszmo Most probably because headphones aren't smart enough to share internet **;-)**.